# Projection/Dot Product Q

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

If we had a vector representing a Boost Pad (like on Mario cart) <4, 2) let's say , and the speed of Mario on the cart let's say, <3, 4> and we said that if you go perpendicular on the Boost Pad (90angle) you won't get any boost, any other angle and you get 3* speed boost...does this mean that any dot product simply gives us information about direction..but not about speed? (at least not directly).

or if someone says that a vector represents the speed of car, let's say, is that just an abstraction that really means it has some quantity/size (i.e. speed) ?? but it doesn't actually mean anything practically until you relate it to some frame of reference (ie. where it started, how long it took, etc)

Hope this makes sense...but for some us non physics people, relating these things to real world things is sometimes quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean that any dot product simply gives us information about direction..but not about speed?

Dot product will give you how much one vector is "in the direction" of the other as a value between -1 through 0 to 1 (from opposite direction through perpendicular to same direction).

In game programming, they use speed as the scalar, the magnitude of the velocity vector. They will often make the distinction between a position vectors (or points) and a direction vector. That is, a point has position, can be translated, etc... but a direction doesn't have a position, and will usually remained normalized so its magnitude isn't important either. They can be used in conjunction with each other. For you mario cart example, the process would be something like:

- add the direction of the mario cart with the direction of the boost to get the new direction (don't forget to normalize the result)
- scale this direction by the boost scalar value
- scale again by the timestep value (delta time)
- add this to mario carts position vector every update to get the new position with boost applied in the direction of the booster.

So to sum up, you are basically have the right intuition, just that direction vectors and position vectors are both vectors but are used to represent different things, direction vectors are arrows that can be located anywhere (their position is not encoded in the data type but their direction) and position vectors are points just like any other that are displacements from the origin, and don't have a direction, and applying vector addition and scalar multiplication you can move a position in a direction a certain amount.

Hope this clears things up.

[This](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) is a good tutorial that might help clear things up too.